# Fast(er) way of computing the cumulative binomial probability?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

While revising for my probability test, I saw this question from one of the previous exams:

You flip a fair coin 100 times. What is the probability that you have less than 45 heads?

My question is a simple one. I know that to calculate the probability of a specific amount of $ n $ heads (or tails), we can use the binomial distribution with formula $ P(X = k) = {n \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k} $, with $ n = 100 $ and $ p = 0.5 $ in this case. I also know that we can compute the chance of $ P(X < k) $ as either $ P(X = 0) + P(X = 1) + ... + P(X = k - 10) $ or $ 1 - (P(X = k) + P(X = k + 1) + ... + P(X = n)) $.

However this is a simple question only worth two points out of over 60 total points. I cannot imagine that you need to compute $ P(X = n) $ *44 separate times* and sum them together for such a small amount of points.

Is there any way to rewrite the formula or apply a different trick to drastically lower the amount of computations you need to do?

Comment: The normal approximation works well for things like this.

Comment: Alternatively, it should be pointed out that in most educational settings for a first course in combinatorics or probability not only are numerical answers for problems like this unnecessary, they are often *discouraged*.  It is far more telling whether a student understands what is going on if you can see an answer with binomial coefficients and products left unsimplified since it implies the thought process used in creating the expression.  $(0.5)^{100}\cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^{44}\binom{100}{k}$ is a perfectly acceptable answer in my book.  If multiple choice with numerical, well... yeah...

Comment: Completely agreed @JMoravitz. The context for this particular question is the multiple-choice section on a final for a course on both probability and statistics, so the author of the test can be fairly sure that the student knows how to use the CLT (or at least should know).

Comment: As for a different trick to drastically lower, note that it is just as probable to get $k$ heads as you are $100-k$ heads with a fair coin.  You can get an exact answer then as $0.5 - (0.5)^{100}\left(0.5\binom{100}{50} + \binom{100}{49}+\binom{100}{48}+\dots+\binom{100}{45}\right)$ due to the symmetry, dropping the number of binomial coefficients you need to calculate down from $45$ to just $6$.  Still too tedious to do in an exam setting, but much less so than before.

Answer (score 1):

@lulu's comment recommending normal approximation was enough for me to solve the question myself. The trick is to indeed use the central limit theorem since we already have a large $ n $.

Since our distribution is a binomial one, we have $ E[X] = \mu = 0.5 \cdot 100 = 50 $ and $ Var(X) = \sigma^2 = 0.5 \cdot 100 (1 - 0.5) = 25 $.

Then, we can compute $ \frac{45-\mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2}} = \frac{45-50}{\sqrt{25}} = -1 $. Looking this up in the Z-table gives $ 0.1587 $. This is close to the exact answer of $ 0.14 $ (and indeed, both 0.14 and 0.16 are marked as correct in the answer sheet).